# how to exclude Hosts from IP range from scanning inside nmap python script

Tags: python-2.7, nmap

would appreciate your advice how to exclude hosts from scanning inside the nm.scan().I have the following script which works perfectly when i enter the range : for example 10.0.0.0/24

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import csv
import nmap                         # import nmap.py module
try:
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()         # instantiate nmap.PortScanner object
except nmap.PortScannerError:
    print('Nmap not found', sys.exc_info()[0])
    sys.exit(0)
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    sys.exit(0)

file = raw_input('\nEnter the name of the file where the scan will be saved/add .csv/: ')
ip_range = raw_input('\nEnter the IP range you want to scan/in the following foramt:x.x.x.x/mask: ')
nmap_arguments= raw_input('\nEnter the nmap arguments : ')
nm.scan(hosts=ip_range, arguments= nmap_arguments)
nm.command_line()                   # get command line used for the scan
nm.scaninfo()                       # get nmap scan informations {'tcp': {'services': '22-443', 'method'nect'}}
nm.all_hosts()                      # get all hosts that were scanned


if (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1]):
    save_csv_data(nm.csv(), path=sys.argv[1])
else:
    save_csv_data(nm.csv())

print "Completed!"
```

but For example if i want to scan the range but exclude 2 hosts , when i enter :`nm.scan(hosts='10.0.0.0/24 --exclude 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, arguments= nmap_arguments)` - it excludes only 10.0.0.1 but still scanning 10.0.0.2.So bottom line is how to enter the IP part inside the nmap()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.Needed to put the arguments first:

```
nm.scan(arguments='-sT --open --exclude X.X.X.X,X.X.X.X',hosts='X.X.X.0/24')
```